# syncsort adding trailer3 ' ; ' makes last column value clip off

Tags: sorting, syncsort

Input files column are compared on fiesr 2 column, 3rd column of A file - B 3rd column B file shud give subtract count having total 8 TTTTTTTTs for count

```
 OPTION COPY                                               
 JOINKEYS FILES=F1,FIELDS=(5,4,A,10,20,A)                  
 JOINKEYS FILES=F2,FIELDS=(1,4,A,6,20,A)                   
 REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:10,20,9,1,5,4,30,1,31,10,F2:27,10)    
 JOIN UNPAIRED,F1                                          
 INREC BUILD=(1,46,27,10,SFF,SUB,37,10,SFF,EDIT=(TTTTTTTT))
 OUTFIL REMOVECC,NODETAIL,                                 
   SECTIONS=(1,54,                                    
             TRAILER3=(1,36,                          
                       ';',                           
                        37,10,                        
                        ';',                          
                        47,7))
```

Output gives last column (subtract count of 7 digits where as it shud be 8 characters
why is tht its taking 55 column instead of 54 define in SECTIONS = 1,54 and didnt given abend for to added ' ; ', for one ' ; ' it added 1 column from 54 to 55 if u see cols ..
for secont added '; ' it simply cut off the last character of file

```
----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+
********************************* Top of Data *********
22222222            ;5060;         1;         1;0000000
```

Comment: You really should click on the About at the top of the screen and read through it. You have asked 15 questions, but it is hard for people to judge how the answers are helpful if you don't do the things the About suggests. You should ask a new question for each problem, or at least detail all your problems in the question first up. Extending with further problems through major edits or by comments makes the topic difficult to follow, so is less beneficial for future searchers. If you just ask and stop at that, people will be less keen to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
47,7))
```

You only ask for seven bytes to be copied from the input, so only seven will be copied, not eight.

I can't see any reason for you to be using OUTFIL with SECTIONS for this.

You are defining your control field for the sections as the entire record. If consecutive records are identical, they will appear as one record, without being totalled even. Try to get test data to show that to yourself.

The use of the SFF for the F2 data when an F2 is not present is creative, but makes things less clear. Are your numbers signed anyway? Also, when you SUBtract you are not allowing for a negative result. Can any of your numbers contain more than eight digits? If so, you will get truncation if the result of the SUB gives you more than eight digits.

```
OPTION COPY                                               
JOINKEYS FILES=F1,FIELDS=(5,4,A,10,20,A)                  
JOINKEYS FILES=F2,FIELDS=(1,4,A,6,20,A)                   
REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:10,20,9,1,5,4,30,1,31,10,F2:27,10)    
JOIN UNPAIRED,F1                                          
INREC BUILD=(1,36,
             C';',
             37,10,
             C';',
             27,10,SFF,
              SUB,
               37,10,SFF,
              EDIT=(TTTTTTTT))
```

Alternative formats to SFF that you can use are UFF (for free-format) and FS, for fixed-format, which has an optional floating sign. I think FS fits your requirement best.

In the EDIT pattern T indicates a "significant digit", so leading zeros will be retained. I indicates an "insignificant digit" so leading zeros will appear as blanks.

```
EDIT=(IIIIIIIT)
```

There are standard patterns, and many examples of the things you can do with EDIT patterns in you manual.

Comment: Hey Bill, I am not using signs, it shud be UFF or something, problem is still with this record, i am getting truncated data , its 8 character(Subtract result column which is last in output) but if you see in result it got 7 digits, 8th one truncated. can you please elaborate why is it bad idea having using OUTFIL with SECTIONS for this. and what should be the correct way to avoid truncation i am having ? they wont go more than 8

Comment: Maybe read through my answer again. If you had 47,8 you will get eight bytes. For SECTIONS, 1) I can see no reason for you to use it for this and 2) Duplicate one line of your test data, run your program, see if that is the result you expect 3) It is making the thing more complex.

Comment: @AgentMahone I've updated the answer to include a suggestion for your format.

Comment: Hey Bill, i got the desired result, thanks to your idea of ,C';',
i didnt knew ';' had to be used with C.. so i used Section which was bad choice

Comment: i am having a hard time supressing the extra zeros of last column, i can do it by Trailer M,10 but it will be a waste of code for such a small thing

Comment: @AgentMahone A constant which can only be Character, like in HEADERn/TRAILERn, does not require the C prefix. Elsewhere, where it cannot be known that the constant is Character, it must be specified. Other constant types are B and X, for instance.